# Generating DocuSign access token in Rails without authorization code via browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docusignapi

I am working on docuSign integration in rails project.
for using the envelope_apis i need access_token. But for generating the access_token i need authorization_code that we can get by putting this url in browser [https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id={{clint_id}}&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/callback](https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id=%7B%7Bclint_id%7D%7D&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/callback).
Then i have to enter the account id & password. After all above process i am getting the authorization_code for access_token api. Also Access_Token valid for 8 hrs.
How we can solve this problem in rails.

I have tried above process to generate the access_token but i want a solution thorugh with i can avoid the authorization_code generation process through the browser.

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only option is to use [JWT](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/), JWT allows you to have the code generated without any user interaction, without having to login to DocuSign.
You need a one-time consent that includes the "impersonation" scope that allow your app to impersonate the user (Since the user won't be in there in person logging in) but this is just needed once, can be done manually if you want and then you can just use the Ruby SDK to call this method to get an access token:

```
 token = api_client.request_jwt_user_token(Rails.configuration.jwt_integration_key, Rails.configuration.impersonated_user_guid, rsa_pk, 3600, @scope)
```